# Merge several timeseries with (differing) missing dates into matrix

Tags: matlab, merge, time-series

I have daily closing prices between '2000-01-01' and '2014-12-31' for 3000 stocks. They all miss out weekends, but additionally, different stocks miss out different days at random.

e.g.

```
stock_1 = { 
    { '2014-12-01'    [1.1] }     % thu
    { '2014-12-02'    [1.2] }     % fri
                                  % mon
    { '2014-12-06'    [1.3] }  }; % tue

stock_2 = { 
    { '2014-12-01'    [2.1] }     % thu
                                  % fri
    { '2014-12-05'    [2.2] }     % mon
    { '2014-12-06'    [2.3] }  }; % tue
```

(Note they are `cell`s representing timeseries not `timeseries` objects).

I'm trying to construct a matrix:

```
mat = [
    [1.1 2.1]    % thu
    [1.2 2.1]    % fri
    [1.2 2.2]    % mon
    [1.3 2.3] ]  % tue
```

How can I merge `stock_1`, `stock_2`, etc. into `mat` so that it replaces missing values with the last good value?

I guess the first step might be a function that takes a date and returns the 'weekday # since beginning of time' and run the first column through that.

So if I had:

```
stock_1a = { 
    { 1    1.1 }     % thu
    { 2    1.2 }     % fri
    { 4    1.3 }  }; % tue
```

... etc., I could preallocate a matrix and fill it out from that.

Then I would have to figure out how to replace the `0` elements.

I could always do it C-style (maximum ugly) with loops and leave it running as it is one-time preprocessing.  But it would make my inner coder weep.

What is a clean way to do this?

Comment: For `fri`, shouldn't it be `[1.2 2.1]` instead of `[1.1 2.2]`?

Comment: So it should -- thanks!  (fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the MATLAB `datenum` type, you should be able to sort this out (You could use datetime to simplify this slightly, but it complicates the interpolation part later). My idea is as follows:

```
% First, generate a list of all of the dates you're looking at
dates = datenum(2000,1,1):datenum(2014,12,31);
% Then determine the day of the week for each
wkdy = weekday(dates);
% Then, exclude the weekends
dates = dates(wkdy~=1 & wkdy~=7); % Saturday is 7, Sunday is 1
```

This gives a list of all of the dates we *expect* stock values for. You can extract the data from the cell arrays as follows:

```
s = reshape([stock_1{:}],2,[]);
stock_1_date = datenum(s(1,:));
stock_1_data = [s{2,:}];
```

You can now fill in the missing data using `interp1`:

```
filled_stock_1_data = interp1(stock_1_date,stock_1_data,dates,'previous');
```

and then repeat for each of the other stock values.